# JS How to get PDF from URL and save to a variable

Tags: javascript, pdf, fetch

I have a link. If it is executed in a browser it triggers PDF-file downloading. I want to get this file in JS from this link and store it to a variable. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried making an AJAX request for the data?  What didn't work?

Comment: I am not familiar with AJAX. Does it work if there are no API?

Comment: If you want to fetch data from the server in the background in JavaScript then AJAX is the technology you're most likely looking for.  Start with some examples and tutorials and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. For example, you can store the pdf into the blob (file-like object).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

```js
const url = 'your link to the PDF'

let pdf;

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    pdf = blob
  })
```

Comment: I get Failed to fetch error

Comment: думаю из-за того что там откуда я скачиваю его не предусмотрено никакого взаимодействия по API.

Comment: What type of error do you get?
Is it CORS one?

Comment: No. I try to run your code in conslole and I get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: You did use the browser console, am I right? Can you run the code on the server-side?
Or open the console on the web page on which you want to work with the file.
For example: if the link is `www.example.com/files/filename.pdf`, open the console on `www.example.com` page.

Comment: Do you think I'm getting this error because I try to fetch PDF from the console on the site with domian that differs from domian of link that contains this PDF?

Comment: If this is true, it will clarify the situation. Because now it is difficult to understand what is the cause of the error.